# How to generate a unique id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running twice the call to google in order to get 20 images (google by default only gives you a set of 10 images for a single call).
However, I need to generate a single unique id for each element i get. Here it is the jQuery I am using but the second set of 10 images gets the same id as per the previous set:

```
 function loadImage() {
    var uniqueId = (function() {
        var counter = 0;
        return function(prefix) {
            counter++;
            return prefix ? prefix + '' + counter : counter;
        }
    })();
    // GOOGLE IMAGES FRONT
    function createGoogleImagesLoad(initialValue) {
        var termS;          
        termS = $("#usp-title").val();
        var _start = initialValue || 1;
        var imagesCount = 10;
        var myCx = 'MY_CX';
        var myKey = 'MY_KEY';
        var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          percentPosition: true
        });
        return function() {
            $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
            q: termS,
            alt: "json",
            searchType: "image",
            cx: myCx,
            num: imagesCount,
            start: _start,
            key: myKey,
            language: "it",
            rights: "cc_publicdomain, cc_attribute",
            filter: "1",
            safe: "high",
            imgType: "photo",
            fileType: "jpg"
            },
          function (data) {
              $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var uniq = uniqueId('thing_');
                var $items = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">'.concat(
                  '<div class="thumbnail">',
                  '<input type="checkbox" name="', uniq, '" value="valuable" id="', uniq, '" />',
                  '<label for="', uniq, '">',
                    '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '">',
                  '</label>',
                '</div>',
              '</div>'));
                $grid.append( $items ).packery( 'appended', $items );
                $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
                $grid.packery();
                $('body').on('change', '.grid .thumbnail :checkbox', function () {
                  var urls = [];
                  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                    urls.push($(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
                  });
                  var str = '';
                  urls.forEach(function (url) {
                    str += '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item"><div class="thumbnail"><img onerror="hideContainer(this)" src="' + url + '"/></div></div>';
                  });
                  $('#usp-custom-4').val(str);
                });
              });
            });
          });
          _start += imagesCount;
      }
    }
    var googleImagesFront = createGoogleImagesLoad();
    googleImagesFront();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you calling `loadImage()` twice? That's the problem, it regenerates the uniqueId function each time, resetting `counter` to 0. Move the `uniqueId` function outside of `loadImage` and it should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an *unique id* you can use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) that implements the standard [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), its use is very simple, you need just add the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and choose the method of the version that you want generate:

```js
console.log('UUID v1:', uuid.v1());
console.log('UUID v4:', uuid.v4());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/node-uuid/1.4.7/uuid.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I answered just with base on the title

Answer (score 0):

The variable `counter` is always getting initialized when you are calling the function. If you place `var counter = 0;` this variable globally or outside the function then you should be able to get unique ids.